An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Object of class Closure could not be converted to string")
I'm trying to set by default the username of the user by default in a empty field is the field is empty but I get an error message when I try do so.
->add('username', TextType::class, [
'label' => 'username',
 data'=> function(User $user){
return is_null($user->getUsername()) ? $user->getUsername(): "";}

I've tried to do it differently like this way but doesn't do anything.
$builder->add('username, TextType::class, [
    'attr' => [
        'class' => 'form-control form-opacity',
        'autofocus' => true
    ],
    'data' => (is_null($builder->getData()->getUsername()) ? $builder->getData()->getUsername() : "username"
]);



Your ternary seems false, if is_null($user->getUsername()) you can't ask for $user->getUsername() because it's null.
try:
return is_null($user->getUsername()) ? "" : $user->getUsername();


You need to use callback to get data, use expression and order of arguments wrong, change  getUsername to correct one. You also can change somehow cheking:
data = is_null($un = $user->getUsername()) ? "": $un;

